# ReadKey while key is not pressed do something

Tags: c#, console, console-application, console.readkey, readkey

I am trying to run my code until <kbd>Esc</kbd> was pressed. Therefore I am using `ReadKey` in my Console

```
var input = Console.ReadKey();
do
{

} while (input.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

but at "ConsoleKey" it says that, ConsoleKey isn't possible in 'bool'. How can I fix that? Or what shall I use instead?

Comment: There is no such error with that code.  It'll loop forever, as it stands, but it'll compile just fine.  If you read a new key in the body of the loop then it'll even work correctly.

Comment: hm it gives an error for me... i probably forgot something in the code...

Comment: The last paragraph of this post was unclear and looked like a completely different question. I've edited the post, feel free to create another question post, OP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo input;
do
{
    input = Console.ReadKey();
} while (input.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

Comment: cut how can i use it like, exiting my program at any point? i'm looking for closing it when ESC is pressed means it has to check all the time. i recently started into programming so i probably dont know how to run multiple threads.

Comment: So this is very dependent what your requirements are and what for an application you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 6):

Is there a particular reason you want to use the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key instead of the conventional <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

You can hook into the `Console.CancelKeyPress` event for the latter and it is standard in the command-line interface world.

`Console.ReadKey()` is blocking, which can be problematic in some loops. Let's take this example:

```
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    CancellationTokenSource cts;

    public void Run()
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = new Task(DoSomething, cts.Token);

        task.Start();

        while (!task.IsCompleted)
        {
            var keyInput = Console.ReadKey(true);

            if (keyInput.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Escape was pressed, cancelling...");
                cts.Cancel();
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        var count = 0;

        while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            count++;

            Console.WriteLine("Background task has ticked ({0}).", count.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This will do some background work using a `Task`, while waiting for <kbd>ESC</kbd> to be pressed. Cancellation works just fine, however it will be stuck at the `Console.ReadKey()` one more time after completion (cancellation).

You could use Win32 API such as [`GetKeyboardState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and check the key codes instead, since it is not blocking. However, I recommend using the `CancelKeyPress` event instead (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>):

```
    void Console_CancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cancelling...");
        cts.Cancel();

        e.Cancel = true;    // Do not terminate immediately!
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ConsoleKeyInfo input;
do
{
    input = Console.ReadKey();
} while (input.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

or shorter

```
while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape){}
```

Comment: but the thing is that it doesnt have to ask at the beginning for closing, but all the time waiting for the user to press ESC

Comment: @user3002135 because you can't wait for esc and do something in one thread in one time